# automatic enter login credentials while testing my app (from visual studio 2008)

Tags: asp.net

this is something that i don't want to program, but i was looking for a handy way of logging on to my web app.
i'm building (and testing and running) my webapp over and over again, and here i've been provided a strong password.
needless to say it's not so nice to enter my full user name + strong password 30 times a day.

is there a nifty tool which lives in the background and when i open page localhost/mytestpage.aspx, it will say: "hey, let me type in michel and sdfs%^%gfhg in these two textboxes"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You ask for something that all ready exist on most of the browsers.

Maybe you have disabled on your browser ? (what browser you use ?)

On ie, how you make it save the passwords
http://www.watchingthenet.com/enable-internet-explorer-prompting-to-save-passwords.html

if you site is local and you do not have make it secure, add it to the trusted sites on ie.

Comment: IE8, and when i doubleclick in the username field it shows the latest filled in items, but it isn't filled in at the same moment the page loads....

Comment: FF 3.6.3 also, but as secondary

Comment: @Michel do not doubleclick, just click and ether press the downarrow, ether start typing. When you see the user name select it and if you have permit you see the password automatic added. On google chrome (that is very fast) when you enter the page you see the user name and passwords.

I have add one more link on answer how you enable on ie the save passwords.

Comment: @Aristos: thanks for your suggestion, but in this case i still have to perform some manual interaction, and what i want is that 'the handy tool' fills the textboxes automaticly without me having to do anything.

Comment: @Michel there is a tool like that on google chrome as module add on.

Comment: @aristos: do you know the name?

Comment: Didn't find an answer after all, still typing... Marked as answer for kudo's

Comment: @Michel You do not mark as answer if do not help you. I have edit it, so you can unvote it.